# How to create another instance of (e)shell in a DWIM fashion?

Tags: shell, eshell

I have seen several proposals to run more than one instance of `eshell` (or `shell`) at a time. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532998/how-to-run-multiple-shells-on-emacs) and [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EshellMultipleEshellBuffers). However, they are inconvenient in my view, using peculiar key chords and forcing you to actively invent ad-hoc buffer names. I'd rather like to have a simple DWIM-like function, e.g. `new-eshell`, that creates a fresh instance of `eshell` in an automatically named buffer. Buffer names should be numbered consecutively, i.e., `*eshell1*`, `*eshell2*` etc.

Who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function uses the default naming conventions of `eshell` when called with a non-numeric prefix argument (e.g. <kbd>C-u M-x eshell</kbd>), so consecutive calls create buffers titled, e.g., `*eshell*<2>*`

```
(defun eshell/new ()
  (interactive)
  (eshell t))
```